# How to get the value of a span tag with no class or id specified using PHP

Tags: php, dom

I need help with my question.
How can I get the value of a span tag without class or id specified on it from a website.

Example of it would be here:

website: http://bit.ly/1C0IfkY

Selected Source I only want to get

```
<p data-iceapc="3" data-iceapw="6"><span data-iceapw="2" style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;">11am: 2-0-7 </span>

<span data-iceapw="2" style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;">4pm: 7-2-3 </span>

<span data-iceapw="2" style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;">9pm: _-_-_ </span></p>
```

I don't have any reference on finding the elements maybe someone can.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($Url);
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//span[@style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo  $node->nodeValue;
```

}

Comment: Hello I was able to compose a xpath query but the problem now is that it returns nothing
Here's the code

$dom = new DOMDocument();
 @$dom->loadHTML($Url);
 
  
 $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
 $nodes = $xpath->query("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/article/div/p/span[3]");
 foreach ($nodes as $node) {
     echo  $node->nodeValue;
  
}

help me to troubleshoot the problem thanks

Comment: first, dont you *shutup operator* (@) - it will suppress error and then you dont know if error happend. Site is heavily javascripted, you have to look at pure html. for now, u can use this query `$query = '//span[@style="font-size:25px; color:#98293D;"]'`

Comment: See my code above using your query. Still return an empty or white  or nothing prints on the page

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners for links on Stack Exchange. The *only* valid reason to use them is when you need to save characters. You *don't* need to do that in questions or answers here. Using them makes the link, and your post, look like spam or otherwise nefarious (e.g. attempting to spread malware).

Answer (score 1):

These are the jQuery paths:

```
$("#content_box > article > div > p:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(1)"); //value 1
$("#content_box > article > div > p:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(3)"); // value 2
$("#content_box > article > div > p:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(5)"); //value 3
```